# Resizing textarea in a table affecting other TR's margin

Tags: html, css

I have textarea in a td element as a field for description as shown in the picture below.
[image]

When i resized the textarea vertically, it work just fine[image]

but...

[image]

when I resized the textarea to its original height, it affects the other TD like it shown in the 3rd image.

What I want it to prevent if from happening.

**Note: It only happens in Chrome, Firefox can handle this problem.**

**EDIT:**

```
Here is the fiddle link.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kvKZu/42/

Comment: Add your html code here or in fiddle

Comment: It is better to use divs for such type of layout. Tables are for data representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `height:100%` to `height:auto` for `img` tag

```
<tr>
<td rowspan="6" style="width:200px;"> <image scr="#" style="width:100%; height:auto;" ></image> </td>
</tr>
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/kvKZu/48/

Comment: Correct solution. Alternatively you can give the td elements a fixed height, even 1px would work as the content expands the height as necessary.